# What is the maximum possible value of determinant of a matrix whose entries either 0 or 1?

Tags: matrices, optimization, determinant

My question is simply the title:

> What is the maximum possible value of determinant of a matrix whose entries either 0 or 1 ?

Comment: Since the determinant is the sum of $\,n!\,$ products of elements of the matrix chosen in a particular way, I'd say the maximum value is $\,n!\,$ ...but I've no example to offer.

Comment: $n!$ is impossible.

Comment: There can't be any example for that

Comment: An upper bound that is smaller than $n!$ is $n^{n/2}$. Google Hadamard's inequality.

Comment: I can offer an example for $n-1.$ Taking $a_{ii}=0$ and $a_{ij}=1$ if $i\neq j.$

Comment: But for your energetic claims, @MherSafaryan, I see no proof or even hint...

Comment: @DonAntonio, proof of what?

Comment: Of any of your claims below my first comment, @MherSafaryan

Comment: Do you need some help to understand that, @DonAntonio?

Comment: Oh, dear: not at all,  @MherSafaryan...hehe. It's just that it was **you** who asked, I offered a first, rather gross bound, and you claim that that is impossible...just like that.

Comment: And no: it was **not** obvious, or better: as obvious as your question could have been.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273560/do-determinants-of-binary-matrices-form-a-set-of-consecutive-numbers) in another thread:

> In fact, I don't even know how large the determinant of a 0-1 matrix can be. The Hadamard's bound for the absolute determinant of an $n\times n$ 0-1 matrix is $\frac{(n+1)^{(n+1)/2}}{2^n}$ (online [ref. 1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardsMaximumDeterminantProblem.html) and [ref. 2](http://oeis.org/A003432)), and the bound is sharp if and only if there exists a Hadamard matrix of order $n+1$. Yet, to my knowledge, there is no known sharp upper bound for the absolute determinant of a general $n\times n$ 0-1 matrix.

Comment: Hm, can someone explain (or direct me to someplace) to understand why this answer is a community wiki? I've not dealt with community wikis before, so just curious.

Comment: @CalvinLin See an explanation [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/community-wiki). In the present case I turned my answer into a community wiki one on purpose, because I didn't think simply *quoting my own question verbatim* deserves any reputation points.

Answer (score 5):

A few examples of $\{0,1\}$-matrices (with the largest determinants $-$ according to [OEIS-A003432](http://oeis.org/A003432)):

$n=2$:
$\quad\det\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\bf{1} & 0 \\
\bf{1} & \bf{1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
=1;$

$n=3$:
$\quad\det\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\bf{1} & 0 & \bf{1} \\
\bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0 \\
0 & \bf{1} & \bf{1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
=2;$

$n=4$:
$\quad\det\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\bf{1} & 0 & \bf{1} & 0 \\
\bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0 & \bf{1} \\
0 & \bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0 \\
0 & 0& \bf{1} & \bf{1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
=3;$

$n=5$:
$\quad\det\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\bf{1} & 0 & \bf{1} & 0 & 0\\
\bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0 & \bf{1} & 0 \\
0 & \bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0 &\bf{1}\\
0 & 0 & \bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0 \\
\bf{1} & 0 & 0 & \bf{1} & \bf{1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
=5;$

$n=6$:
$\quad\det\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\bf{1} & 0 & \bf{1} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0 & \bf{1} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0 &\bf{1} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0 & \bf{1}\\
\bf{1} & 0 & 0 & \bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0\\
\bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0 & 0 & \bf{1} & \bf{1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
=9;$

$n=7$:
$\quad\det\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 \\
\bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 \\
\bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 \\
   0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 \\
   0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 \\
\bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 \\   
   0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
=32;$

$n=8$:
$\quad\det\left(
\begin{array}
\bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 \\
\bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 \\
\bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 \\
   0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 \\
   0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 \\
\bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 \\
   0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 \\
   0 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
=56;$

Comment: Very nice! I was also looking for patterns of symmetry but didn't search too long... (I stopped after having brute-forced $n=4$ with $2^{16}$ variants of the matrix ... ;-))

Comment: Yes, we can find first 8 matrices among striped matrices ($\searrow \searrow \searrow$). What about others $n$ ???

Comment: Impressive!  Were you looking only among the striped ones? For $n=9$ you might need $17$ stripes, so you did not reach the largest value from the list?

Comment: @orangeskid: I looked among the striped shapes just to reduce the search area. The striped matrices provide maximum value for determinant only for small $n$ ($n\le 8$): $$n=9: \qquad det_{max}(striped) =125 \textrm{ vs } det_{max}=144; $$ $$n=10: \qquad det_{max}(striped)=312 \textrm{ vs } det_{max} = 320;$$ $$n=11: \qquad det_{max}(striped)=1215 \textrm{ vs } det_{max}=1458;$$

Comment: Interesting!  A question: given a striped determinant with $0$, $1$, is it largest among striped determinants with entries in $[0,1]$? Since it is not linear in the entries anymore...

Comment: @orangeskid:

small update:
$n=10$ has $det_{max}(striped) = 315$;
and $n=11$ admits striped (cyclic) solution:
$$
n=11:\qquad det\left(
\begin{array}{lllllllllll}
1&0&1&0&0&0&1&1&1&0&1\\
1&1&0&1&0&0&0&1&1&1&0\\
0&1&1&0&1&0&0&0&1&1&1\\
1&0&1&1&0&1&0&0&0&1&1\\
1&1&0&1&1&0&1&0&0&0&1\\
1&1&1&0&1&1&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&1&0&1&1&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&1&0&1&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&1&0&1&1&0&1\\
1&0&0&0&1&1&1&0&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&1&1&1&0&1&1
\end{array}
\right) = 1458
$$

Regarding striped determinant with entries in $[0,1]$: it looks so, but I have no proof.

Comment: @Oleg567: So interesting! Btw, just found [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52851/find-the-maximum-determinant-for-each-size-toeplitz-matrix).