# A determinants problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics

If a determinant of order three has only 1 or -1 as its elements, what would be its maximum value? 
I thought about this problem, but I am not getting an idea to start this problem. 
Help is appreciated. :D

Comment: See : hadamard-matrix

Comment: An obvious upper bound is $6$, as there are six products in the development.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. @YvesDaoust

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_maximal_determinant_problem

Comment: @RyanBendtner: can you substantiate ? Six times one is six, isn't it ?

Comment: @RyanBendtner: don't confuse maximum and upper bound. $6$ is an upper bound, that's undisputable. By the way, the same as that given by mvw.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot! @YvesDaoust

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/591488/11619).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is essentially one way to get three linearly independent rows: change one sign, then another.

$$\left|\begin{matrix}1&1&1\\\bar1&1&1\\\bar1&\bar1&1\end{matrix}\right|=4.$$

---

**Other argument**:

Perform Gauss elimination on the matrix. After one round of elimination, the new coefficients are either $0$ or $\pm2$, and if the matrix is in triangular form, the maximum determinant is $1\cdot2\cdot2$. If a second round is needed, the new coefficient is $0$ or $\pm4$, which could yield $1\cdot2\cdot4$. But this is impossible as the obvious upper bound is $6$.

Answer (score 1):

An upper bound can be obtained from the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n_.C3.97_n_matrices) of the determinant by Leibniz
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{sgn}{sgn}
\DeclareMathOperator{det}{det}
\det A = \underbrace{\sum_{\pi \in S_n}}_{\tiny\lvert S_n\rvert = n!}\underbrace{\sgn(\pi)}_{\tiny \in \{ -1,1\}} \underbrace{ \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i\pi(i)}}_{\tiny \in \{ -1,1\}}
\le n!
$$
where $S_n$ is the symmetric group of order $n$, containing all permutations of size $n$.

Comment: How do you arrive at this equation?