# Is there a 12x12 symmetric Hadamard matrix?

Tags: matrices, hadamard-matrices

More generally, is there a simple condition for which $n$ there are symmetric Hadamard matrices of order $n$?

This set of $n$ is closed under multiplication via the Kronecker product.

Comment: I don't know about the general case, but Sylvester's construction gives symmetric Hadamard matrices of orders $2^k$, $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$.

Comment: It would be useful if you provided some context for your question, why are you interested in $12\times 12$ matrices? What strategies did you try to approach this problem?

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591531/11619) I used a 12x12 Hadamard matrix I copied from Neil Sloane's page. I don't rememeber for sure, but that may be by the Paley construction. Feel free to check whether that can be transformed into a symmetric by the allowed transformations :-)

Comment: On [Neil Sloane's page](http://neilsloane.com/hadamard/) it is said that the 12x12 Hadamard matrix is unique up to isomorphism. So either you can transform it into symmetric, or no symmetric Hadamard-12 exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a construction that generates a symmetric Hadamard matrix of order $2(q+1)$ for any prime $q\equiv1\bmod4$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley_construction), especially Paley Construction II). Since $q=5$ qualifies, the required order-12 matrix is a solved problem. The construction may also be modified for the case where $q$ is one greater than a multiple of $4$ and a *power* of a prime, like $q=3^2=9$ giving a symmetric Hadamard matrix of order 20.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the conjectures for (skew-)symmetric Hadamard matrices are "the same" : for every $n\equiv 0 \mod 4$ there exists a (skew-)symmetric Hadamard matrix of size $n$ ( skew-symmetric means $H+H^t = 2 I$).  Check out this [talk](https://people.clas.ufl.edu/sin/files/UMSHadamard.pdf), especially p.20. Good luck!

$\bf{Added:}$ It would be interesting to see how the Paley I $H_1$ and Paley II $H_2$ constructions are related in the case $n=12$. The first is skew-symmetric, the second symmetric. Sloane says they are equivalent. Maybe there exist $D$ a $\pm 1$ diagonal matrix, $P$  a permutation matrix, such that

$$H_2 = H_1 \cdot D \cdot P$$

Another case where both Paley I and Paley II work is for $n=60 = 59 + 1 = 2(29+1)$.

Comment: A useful link!!

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix): "Two Hadamard matrices are considered equivalent if one can be obtained from the other by negating rows or columns, or by interchanging rows or columns."

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Yes indeed. Note that conjugating with an orthogonal keeps it (skew-)symmetric. So perhaps in this case we can do it one-sided. Cheers!

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: A friendly presentation :-)