# Maximum determinant of a $(0,1)$-matrix

Tags: matrices, number-theory, determinant, discrete-optimization

Suppose that the elements of an n- order determinant are either $0$ or $1$,  I wonder the maximum and the minimum of the determinant.

Furthermore,  I wonder all  possible values of it.  What if I change the question that the elements are either $1$ or $-1$?

Comment: What has your question to do with `number-theory`?

Comment: First question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425417/what-is-the-maximum-possible-value-of-determinant-of-a-matrix-whose-entries-eith

Comment: @José Carlos Santos My opinion is that the question is closely related to integer combination. Therefore,  the possible solutions might to do with number theory.

Answer (score 2):

Closed forms for the maximum and minimum are not known, but there are decent bounds available. For a $(0,1)$ $n\times n$ matrix $A$, we have
$$|\det A|\leq \frac{(n+1)^{(n+1)/2}}{2^n}$$
and for a $(-1,1)$ matrix the maximum value is $2^{n-1}$ times the maximum $(0,1)$ value. See [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardsMaximumDeterminantProblem.html) for more info.

Note that in both cases the minimum value is the additive inverse of the maximum value for $n\geq 2$, since we can permute two rows to achieve this value.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant of a matrix $A=a_{i,j}$,$1 \le i,j \le n$ is given by (where $S_n$ is the set of all permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)$ is the sign of a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ ($-1$ for odd, $1$ for even)

$$\det(A)=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i, \sigma(i)}$$

so an alternating sum of terms, which are each products of $n$ terms.
All these product terms are $0$ or $1$, so the greatest value is achieved when all even permutations yield $1$ while odd permutations yield $0$, e.g. So $\frac{n!}{2}$ is best (not sure if it's reachable though).

With $1,-1$ it's more complicated. Maybe check out [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/425417/4280) or [this reference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardsMaximumDeterminantProblem.html)

Comment: Since it is tough to calculate the best approximation,  I wonder whether it is proved to be a "Polynomial  problem" or not.

Comment: @TamshinDion the mathworld article (second link) shows it's well understood ven in the case of $-1,1$ matrices, where we have Hadamard matrices to find the max. The max itself is easier to find.

Comment: .Thanks for mentioning me that.  Link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardMatrix.html

Comment: @TamshinDion rather [mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardsMaximumDeterminantProblem.html](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardsMaximumDeterminantProblem.html) for the more general case.